# Locking focus on batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a simple batch file in windows that I run on startup that presents the user with a menu to start certain applications. However by default, whenever I open one of these applications the focus goes to that window and off of the batch file. Is there a way to maintain, or re-divert focus onto the batch window?

Thanks

EDIT: Got it to do what I wanted. Used foxidrives suggestion to start them minimized but they were still taking focus. So I made a short VBScript to make the cmd window the active window after each call and the combination of the two worked. Thanks!

Comment: [The arms race between programs and users](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx)

Comment: That makes sense. Figured there might be a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no command to steal the focus. As Bill_Stewart posted, that would be a dangerous feature that grants the program too much power over the user. You can however start the applications minimized (they will still be the active window), and then build and call a VBScript to make your batch window the active window:

```
start "" /MIN "application.exe"
cscript /nologo myVBScript.vbs
```

myVBScript.vbs

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "myBatchFile"
WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.AppActiavte "myBatchFile"
```

I've read that several people have had trouble with AppActivate on Windows 7. It was not functioning for me, and instead of bringing my target window to the foreground it just blinked in the task bar. Calling it a second time however, for some reason, brought it to the foreground and made it the active window, which is what I wanted. Hope this helps anybody else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the start command with the /min switch then the application will be minimised and the batch file should remain visible:

```
@echo off
pause
echo launching notepad
start "" /min notepad
echo notepad is active
pause
```

Comment: Thanks. However, when they start minimized they're still made the active window. Built a short VBScript to make my batch the active window but it only worked with /MIN so thank you.

Comment: My test with notepad works here in Windows 8.1 so it seems that it depends on the application.

Comment: Coming here in 2024 - your tip worked for me and returned focus back to cmd.exe:  *start "" /min notepad*

Answer (score 0):

you can't lock the focus to your command prompt window. But what you could do is to set the TopMost flag of the command prompt window. There is a Win32 function called `SetWindowPos` which does that. Maybe there are some ready to use command line tools around which are doing this for you. Or, if you have visual studio installed, try to compile this one here: [How to set a console application window to be the top most window (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369993/how-to-set-a-console-application-window-to-be-the-top-most-window-c)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check that out when I get the chance.