# retain console application window even when user clicks the background

Tags: c#

I have created a console application in c#.And I managed to disable the close button of the console window.And it works.I am curious to know, is there any way to retain the console window even when the user clicks background as done in forms application by show dialogue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: As in [How to set a console application window to be the top most window (C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369993/how-to-set-a-console-application-window-to-be-the-top-most-window-c) ?

Comment: Please show the code that disables the close button, I am curious about that.

Comment: @alex : Yes it works,But i wish to make the console window modal